# Determine an expression for X from the truth table

Tags: regular-expressions

I am having a problem with determining an expression for X from the truth table below. Can you help me to do this? Thanks in advance

[image: https://i.imgur.com/YyyxJDc.jpg]

Comment: What are your initial thoughts? Can you write a long expression?

Answer (score 0):

An easy one is:

$((\neg A)\wedge (\neg B) \wedge (C)) \vee ((\neg A)\wedge ( B) \wedge (\neg C)) \vee ((\neg A)\wedge ( B) \wedge ( C)) \vee (( A)\wedge ( B) \wedge (\neg C)) $

Comment: Now *simply* apply DeMorgan's laws, . . .